# Postgresql LAG() Function to show zero instead of null

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's my code:

```
WITH WEEKCTE AS (SELECT date_trunc('week', day::date) AS anchor, AVG(value) AS average
FROM daily_metrics
WHERE metric = 'daily-active-users'
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor)

SELECT*,
(average - lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor))/lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor) AS delta
FROM WEEKCTE
```

Here's the result:
[image]

But I want the first row of delta to show 0 instead of null.
I tried with lag(average,0,0) instead of lag(average) to offset by 0 and set default to 0 but it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `coalesce()`:

```
  SELECT w.*,
        coalesce( (average - lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor)) /
                   lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor), 0) AS delta
  FROM WEEKCTE w;
```

Note that you do not need the CTE.  You can use window functions and aggregation together:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', day::date) AS anchor,
       AVG(value) AS average,
       COALESCE(average / LAG(AVG(value)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(day)) - 1, 0)
FROM daily_metrics
WHERE metric = 'daily-active-users'
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce()`

```
WITH WEEKCTE AS (SELECT date_trunc('week', day::date) AS anchor, AVG(value) AS average
FROM daily_metrics
WHERE metric = 'daily-active-users'
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor)

SELECT*,
coalesce(((average - lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor))/lag(average) OVER (ORDER BY anchor)), 0) AS delta
FROM WEEKCTE
```

Thought its not possible to get any 0 for `lag(average)`, its best practice to avoid divided by 0 possibilities.

```
SELECT*,
coalesce(((average - /coalesce(lag(average), 1) OVER (ORDER BY anchor))/coalesce(lag(average), 1) OVER (ORDER BY anchor)), 0) AS delta
FROM WEEKCTE
```